# Multiple grid areas in one gridster instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

Lets say i have a functioning [Gridster](http://gridster.net/) grid

```
<div class="gridster">
  <ul>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to make it so that one grid can have three sections: header, body and footer.

For example

```
<div class="gridster">
  <ul>
    <!-- header begin -->
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <!-- header end -->
    <!-- body begin -->
    <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <!-- body end -->
    <!-- footer begin -->
    <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <!-- footer end -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is having three independent grid sections in one gridster instance. There is no fixed row count for neither the header nor footer. The user should be able to drag widgets between the header, body and footer and it will then accordingly increase the header and footer height accordingly.

I would like to avoid using multiple gridster instances for this as the data of the grid will be saved and the body can be even 12 A4 pages long and with multiple instances the execution time and memory usage is much larger.

Does anyone have any possible ideas on how to achieve this?

**Update (29/04):**

On the layout side I have found that the best solution is:

```
<div class="gridster">
  <ul class="gheader"></ul>
  <ul class="gbody"></ul>
  <ul class="gfooter"></ul>
</div>
```

With this I can have three grid areas when calling `$(".gridster ul").gridster();`.

When I have statically some widgets loaded in, then I can move them around in their respective `ul` nicely but when I dynamically add a widget with the `add_widget` function then the widget gets added to the first `ul` only (in this case `.gheader`) and dragging between them still needs to be figured out.

My current code to init gridster:

```
Formbuilder.initGrid = function(selector){
  $(selector).gridster({
    widget_margins: [0, 0],
    widget_base_dimensions: [this.baseWidth, this.baseHeight],
    max_cols: 10,
    min_rows: 10,
    max_size_x: 10,
    shift_larger_widgets_down: false,
    resize: {
      enabled: true,
      max_size: [10, 10]
    }
  });

  gridster = $(selector).gridster().data("gridster");

  return gridster;
}
```